# I am unable to pass params to a route using React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a button on the header to activate EDIT mode on a page, or SAVE when edit mode is done.

```js
type TabProfileParamList = {
  ProfileScreen: { isEditing: boolean };
};

const TabFourStack = createStackNavigator<TabProfileParamList>();

function ProfileNavigator1() {
  const r = useRoute();
  const n = useNavigation();

  return (
    <TabFourStack.Navigator>
      <TabFourStack.Screen
        initialParams={{ isEditing: false }}
        name="ProfileScreen"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <MyBtn
              buttonStyle={{ padding: 0 }}
              text={r.params.isEditing ? "Save" : "Edit"}
              onPress={() => {
                n.setParams({ isEditing: !r.params.isEditing });
              }}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </TabFourStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

On the lines containing `r.params.isEditing` I am getting I place the cursor on top of `.params`:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

And top of `.isEditing`:

> Property 'isEditing' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)

And here where I need it:

```js
export function ProfileScreen1(): JSX.Element {
  const r = useRoute();

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      {r.params.isEditing ? <MembershipScreen /> : <ProfileContent />}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

So, every time I click on the SAVE/EDIT button, the app crashes.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I'm hazarding a guess here. 

`useRoute()` returns the route prop of the screen it's inside.

`isEditing` is a route prop of the `TabFourStack` screen. Calling `useRoute()` inside `ProfileScreen` works because `ProfileScreen` is inside the `TabFourStack` screen.

Calling `useRoute()` inside the `ProfileNavigator` component is returning the route props of whatever screen `ProfileNavigator` is inside. `isEditing` is not a prop of whatever that is. Hence the crash